# Comapre sqlserver table with the query results

Tags: sql-server

I have a table 'A' with few columns say - ID, firstname,lastname,address and phonenumber.
I am populating this table on a daily basis using a query that joins few tables.

Now before loading the table, I need to check my query results against the table data and see if the data is already present.

1. If my table data and query results matches, then no need to insert the record.
2. if my table data and query result doesn't match then need to insert the record.
3. If the table data and the query result has updated record, then the data has to be inserted.
   that is, If the Id,lastname,firstname, address are all same and only the PhoneNumber is changes in my query result. Then this record should also be inserted in the table A.

I tried a query to identify the Point -3, But I'm stuck how to proceed further and make thhose records to be inserted in table A.

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
  FROM
  (
  SELECT * FROM 
  ( SELECT [ID],FirstName, LastName,[PhoneNumber],[ExpDate] FROM  [SCRATCH].[dbo].[A]     
  UNION ALL
    SELECT D.[ID],FirstName, LastName,,[PhoneNumber],[ExpDate] FROM  
S JOIN D ON D.ID = S.ID) Tbls
    GROUP BY [ID],FirstName, LastName,[PhoneNumber],[ExpDate]
    HAVING COUNT(*)<2) Diff
```

Comment: What you are talking about here is a `MERGE` or "upsert" (a 
portmanteau of update and insert). A quick search of these terms will give you 1,000's of resources.

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of rows that don't match between two tables - you can use EXCEPT.  For example:

```
SELECT [ID],FirstName, LastName,[PhoneNumber],[ExpDate] FROM [SCRATCH].[dbo].[A]     
 Except
 SELECT D.[ID],FirstName, LastName,,[PhoneNumber],[ExpDate] FROM S
```

From this - we can then construct an insert statement, here is an example with data:

```
Declare @tableS Table (ID int, FirstName varchar(30), LastName varchar(30), PhoneNumber varchar(12), ExpDate date);
 Insert Into @tableS (ID, FirstName, LastName, PhoneNumber, ExpDate)
 Values (1, 'Test', 'Testing', '111-111-1111', '2021-03-01');

Declare @tableA Table (ID int, FirstName varchar(30), LastName varchar(30), PhoneNumber varchar(12), ExpDate date)
 Insert Into @tableA (ID, FirstName, LastName, PhoneNumber, ExpDate)
 Values (2, 'Test', 'Testing', '222-222-2222', '2021-03-01')
      , (3, 'Test', 'Testing', '333-333-3333', '2021-03-01');

 --==== Insert new/changed rows into @tableS
 Insert Into @tableS (ID, FirstName, LastName, PhoneNumber, ExpDate)
 Select ID, FirstName, LastName, PhoneNumber, ExpDate From @tableA
 Except
 Select ID, FirstName, LastName, PhoneNumber, ExpDate From @tableS;

 Select * From @tableS;

 Insert Into @tableA (ID, FirstName, LastName, PhoneNumber, ExpDate)
 Values (1, 'Test', 'Testing', '111-222-3333', '2021-03-02')
      , (4, 'Test', 'Testing', '444-444-4444', '2021-03-04');

 --==== Insert new/changed rows into @tableS
 Insert Into @tableS (ID, FirstName, LastName, PhoneNumber, ExpDate)
 Select ID, FirstName, LastName, PhoneNumber, ExpDate From @tableA
 Except
 Select ID, FirstName, LastName, PhoneNumber, ExpDate From @tableS;

 Select * From @tableS;
```

You probably will need to adjust the columns used with EXCEPT so you are not comparing the ID and the ExpDate - but this should get you started.